# Communication between classes

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have heavily modified the MS mandelbrot [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9/sourcecode?fileId=44756&pathId=962809525) and am about halfway to releasing an app based on it.

I am trying to link the pages together now, but I'm noticing the primary class doesn't have access to any of the secondary classes.

The classes appear to be tightly coupled to the pages, and the main class appears to be able to create and load these pages on the fly without ever getting a handle to the class (where I could bind an event to a delegate).

From the mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
public void LoadScenario(Type scenarioClass)
{
    AutoSizeInputSectionWhenSnapped = true;

    // Load the ScenarioX.xaml file into the Frame.
    HiddenFrame.Navigate(scenarioClass, this);

    if (scenarioClass == typeof(TitleScreen))
    {
        // connect event handler here? how?
        //     EventHandler e = scenarioClass.PageEventHandler(HandleChangePageCall);
        // scenarioClass is a Type, so any events are not in scope
    }

    // Get the top element, the Page, so we can look up the elements
    // that represent the input and output sections of the ScenarioX file.
    Page hiddenPage = HiddenFrame.Content as Page;

    // Get each element.
    UIElement input = hiddenPage.FindName("Input") as UIElement;
    UIElement output = hiddenPage.FindName("Output") as UIElement;
    UIElement entireScreen = hiddenPage.FindName("LayoutRoot") as UIElement;

    if (entireScreen == null)
    {
        // Malformed input section.
        NotifyUser(String.Format(
            "Cannot load this screen: {0}.  Make sure root of input section markup has x:Name of 'entireScreen'",
            scenarioClass.Name), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        return;
    }

    if (output == null)
    {
        // Malformed input section.
        NotifyUser(String.Format(
            "Cannot load this screen: {0}.  Make sure root of input section markup has x:Name of 'Output'",
            scenarioClass.Name), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Find the LayoutRoot which parents the input and output sections in the main page.
    Panel panel = hiddenPage.FindName("LayoutRoot") as Panel;

    if (panel != null)
    {
        // Get rid of the content that is currently in the intput and output sections.
        panel.Children.Remove(input);
        panel.Children.Remove(output);
        //panel.Children.Remove(entireScreen);

        //// Populate the input and output sections with the newly loaded content.
        //InputSection.Content = input;
        OutputSection.Content = output;
        //OutputSection.Content = entireScreen;   // doesn't fall within the expected range
    }
    else
    {
        // Malformed Scenario file.
        NotifyUser(String.Format(
            "Cannot load scenario: '{0}'.  Make sure root tag in the '{0}' file has an x:Name of 'LayoutRoot'",
            scenarioClass.Name), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

These classes/pages were tightly bound to a UI control (listbox), but I took that out since the listbox didn't belong in my userflow.

Also in the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
// Change the array below to reflect the name of your scenarios.
// This will be used to populate the list of scenarios on the main page with
// which the user will choose the specific scenario that they are interested in.
// These should be in the form: "Navigating to a web page".
// The code in MainPage will take care of turning this into: "1) Navigating to a web page"
List<Scenario> scenarios = new List<Scenario>
{
    new Scenario() { Title = "Main Title", ClassType = typeof(TitleScreen) },
    new Scenario() { Title = "Images from a file stream", ClassType = typeof(Scenario2) },
    new Scenario() { Title = "Displaying a NineGrid image", ClassType = typeof(Scenario3) },
    new Scenario() { Title = "Using a WriteableBitmap", ClassType = typeof(Scenario4) }
};
```

Should I modify the scenario class to hold instantiations of all these scenarios?

Or should I set up some kind of IPC to pass information back? I'm not sure if Windows Apps can even do IPCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the MainPage class has a static reference to itself, so I can call that to change the secondary pages from the secondary pages:

```
// in the secondary page:
MainPage rootPage = MainPage.Current;
rootPage.SetScreen(2);

// definition in the MainPage class:
public static MainPage Current;
```